# SQLite for Universal Windows Plataform in Unity3d (5.5.3f1). How to do it?

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine, uwp, database-connection

I'm currently working in a project that supports Android, iOS, OSX and not UWP Windows. Now we're trying to add support for UWP, we had a lot of problems and the one we are not founding any solution is how to use SQLite for UWP in Unity. It is possible? If it is how can I do it? Or there is another database we can use to replace SQLite? Please, let me know!

Comment: Have you searched online? When I searched on Google, I found [the first result](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=sqlite+Unity+UWP) is what you want.

Comment: Hello! Have you tried to test it in UWP? I tried but have no success :/

Comment: I don't have Unity3d (5.5.3f1), however, I tested with Unity 2017.2.0b8, it works well.